# How do I insert a string on an array from the strings.xml file

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

How do I insert a string on an array from the strings.xml file, if I enter the following error I get the error **getText(R.string.home)**

> Error: Cannot resolve method 'getText(int)'

```
static String[] titles ={"Home",
        "Profile",
        "Settings",
        "Exit"};
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need a `Context` object in order to be able to call the `getString()` method. The reason you can often write simply `getString(R.string.foo)` rather than something like `mContext.getString(R.string.foo)` is that the `Activity` class is a subclass of `Context`.

How exactly you get a `Context` object will depend on where you're trying to execute this code. In a `Fragment`, you can write `getActivity().getString(R.string.foo)`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try in this way

```
 <string-array name="home">
    <item>Home</item>
    <item>Profile</item>
    <item>Settings</item>
    <item>Exit</item>
</string-array>
```

```
String [] titles= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.home);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use getString() method as follows:

```
static String[] titles ={getString(R.string.home),
        getString(R.string.profile),
        getString(R.string.settings),
        getString(R.string.exit)};
```

If you are not calling this in an Activity but in a fragment, you must use getActivity().getString.
Hope that helps.

Comment: NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

put you string array in like this on strings.xml file

```
<string-array name="menuItems">
        <item>Home</item>
        <item>Profile</item>
        <item>Settings</item>
        <item>Exit</item>
    </string-array>
```

Access in your java file like this

```
String [] fruitsArray= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menuItems);
```